# How to Update outputpanel from commandbutton which is inside the datatable using primefaces

Tags: primefaces

```
Commandbutton with id("myButtonId2") works fine. I mean it updates "myOutputPanel"
```

but commandbutton(myButtonId) which is inside datatable doesn't update outputPanel. I found the suggestions and tried with the following,
    update=":myForm:myOutputPanel"
    update="@myForm"
    update=":myOutputPanel"
    But none of them worked...

```
Here is the snippet...
 <h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
      <p:panel id="myPanel">
         <p:dataTable id="myDatatable">
            <p:column style="width:4%">  
              <p:commandButton id="myButtonId" actionListener="#{bean.showPanel}" update="myOutputPanel"/>
            </p:column>
         </p:dataTable>
         <p:commandButton id="myButtonId2" update="myOutputPanel"/>
        </p:panel>

     <p:outputPanel id="myOutputPanel" rendered="#{bean.show}">
      //some stuff
     </p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to put your `<p:outputPanel />` inside a `<p:panel />`

and add a "widgetVar" attribute

For example : `<p:panel widgetVar="var" [..]>`

and just update the panel directly with `update="@widgetVar(var)"`